# Conditionally set attributes in MongoDB based on form fields

Tags: python, form, hash-map, mongodb

I have code which gets data from a `POST` request (`request.form` dict), compares with corresponding attribute in object `accident` and does some action. The code looks needlessly verbose.  How can I optimize it?

```
if accident.status == 1:
    if request.form.get('reason') \
        and request.form['reason'] != accident.reason:
        accident.set_reason(request.form['reason'], current_user)
    if request.form.get('note') \
        and request.form['note'] != accident.note:
        accident.note = request.form['note']
else:
    if request.form.get('priority') \
        and int(request.form['priority']) != accident.priority:
        accident.set_priority(current_user, int(request.form['priority']))
    if request.form.get('status') \
        and int(request.form['status']) != accident.status:
        accident.set_status(current_user, int(request.form['status']))
    if request.form.get('duration') \
        and int(request.form['duration']) != accident.duration:
        accident.duration = int(request.form['duration'])
    if request.form.get('service_status') \
        and int(request.form['service_status']) != accident.service_status:
        accident.set_service_status(int(request.form['service_status']))
```

Below is a stripped down version of `Accident` class, which is inconsistent because there are many fields, and sometimes setting a field requires many additional actions like logging or checking for user rights. The class derives from [MongoEngine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html) schema class.

```
class Accident(Document):
    priority = IntField(choices=PRIORITIES)
    status = IntField(choices=STATUSES, default=0)
    duration = IntField()
    region = StringField()
    service_status = IntField(choices=(0, 1, 2))
    reason = StringField(default=u"")
    note = StringField(default=u"")

    def set_priority(self, user=None, priority=None):
        self.priority = priority
        # Functions starting with `set_` do some activity that has
        # nothing to do with setting and validating a value. That's
        # why i don't use @property decorator. `to_history(user)` is
        # just an example.
        to_history(user)

    def set_status(self, user, status):
        self.status = status
        to_history(user)

    def set_reason(self, reason, user):
        self.reason = reason
        to_history(user)

    def set_service_status(self, ss):
        self.service_status = ss
        to_history(user)
```

If this is necessary, how can i improve class structure? It seems like I can't use `@property` decorator for setters, because my setters accept additional parameters. However I don't like the idea of writing a setter for all possible attributes. I use `request.form.get(foo)` instead of `foo in request.form`, because the dictionary may contain `foo: None` pair, and I don't want to accidentally set an attribute to `None`.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not 100% sure there is a particularly elegant way to write this. If the code did not have a different body for each `if` statement, one could rewrite it like this

```
FORM_VALUES = {
    "priority": accident.priority,
    "status": accident.status,
    "duration": accident.duration,
    "service_status": accident.service_status
}

for key in FORM_VALUES:
    if request.form.get(key) and int(request.form[key]) != FORM_VALUES[key]:
        # As you use different functions for setting the values, this isn't possible
        request.set_value(key, request.form[key])
```

However, that is not the case, so don't get your hopes up. Regardless, there are still improvements to be made:

- You're not checking that the header values are valid integers. I'd recommend either checking they are by using `string.isdigit()` or otherwise wrapping your calls to `int()` in a try except block.
- You can use `'reason' in request.form` instead of `request.form.get('reason')`; they have the same meaning in the places you've used them, but the first is easier to read.
- It might be good if you used an enumeration for the values to `Accident.status`. As it is, checking that `accident.status == 1` doesn't tell me anything; using a meaningful identifier might solve this. You can do this quite simply, by just assigning values to each identifier: `PENDING, IN_PROGRESS, FINISHED = STATUSES`. I've used some random names, and assumed that there are 3 possible statuses, change this to be accurate. Then in your function, instead of `if accident.status == 1`, we can have `if accident.status == PENDING`, which is a lot easier to understand without needing to know the meaning of each value of status.
- In general, you should try and be consistent with the ordering of your arguments: your `set_reason` takes first a `reason`, then a `user` argument, while all of your other methods take the `user` argument first. The `set_service_status` doesn't take a `user` argument at all, which is fairly impressive, considering it uses a user variable in the function.

Overall not bad code. I don't agree with your comments on how `@property` would be inappropriate there, but it's far from the end of the world. In general, I'd try and be more careful to validate user input, but it may be that you do not need to worry about that.

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to see this as my goal:<sup>1</sup>

```
if accident.status == 1:
    transfer_from_form(request.form, accident, [
        ('reason', str),
        ('note', str),
    ])
else:
    transfer_from_form(request.form, accident, [
        ('priority', int),
        ('status', int),
        ('duration', int),
        ('service_status', int),
    ])
```

Let's see what it takes to get there!  I imagine that `transfer_from_form()` could look like this:

```
def transfer_from_form(form, obj, fields):
    for field, conv in fields:
        if form.get(field) and form[field] != getattr(obj, field):
            setattr(obj, field, conv(form[field]))
```

Notionally, that would perform the equivalent of assignments like `accident.service_status = int(request.form['service_status'])` whenever the form field is set and the attribute on `accident` doesn't already contain that value.

Then there is the pesky issue of how to pass the `user` parameter.  I would argue that the `user` should be stored in the session somewhere, and the `Accident`'s setter method could pluck it out of the session instead of having it passed in explicitly.  You didn't specify which web framework you are using, so I can't tell you exactly how to accomplish that.

The `Accident` class's setters appear to be wrappers around the MongoEngine fields' setters, with some audit logging inserted.  Instead of defining methods like `set_service_status()`, you could hook in the audit logging by [monkey patching](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-January/076194.html) the MongoEngine fields' setters.  Not only would the code read more smoothly, you wouldn't be relying on the goodwill of the users of the `Accident` class to refrain from setting `accident.service_status` directly instead of going through the approved `set_service_status()` method.

---

<sup>1</sup> There is some redundancy here.  Ideally, I shouldn't have to declare that `'reason'` is a `str` and `'service_status'` is an `int`, because the types should be deducible from the fact that they are a `StringField` and `IntField`, respectively.  If you can figure out how to accomplish that deduction, that would be even better.

Comment: I'm also thinking (broadly) about "closure" to handle that pesky user parameter.

Comment: Shouldn't `obj.getattr(field)` be `getattr(obj, field)` (similarly `obj.setattr(...)` vs `setattr(obj, ...)`)? Anyway, totally agreed on refactoring that part out, although I would prefer multiple calls over passing a list of parameters.

Comment: @MichaelUrman Thanks for spotting the error. Corrected in Rev 2.

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget that `dict.get()` can also take a default:

```
if request.form.get('reason', accident.reason) != accident.reason:
    accident.set_reason(request.form['reason'], current_user)
```

...that makes it a little shorter.

**EDIT:** or even

```
def needs_update(name):
    return request.form.get(name, getattr(accident, name)) != getattr(accident, name)

if needs_update('reason'):
    ...
```

Barring @BluePepper's elegant solution, you could probably build a change list and then iterate through the fields that need updating.

This is very cheesy, but you could break the value check and the update in two parts. I did this fast, sorry, but I hope the general idea is clear:

```
form = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
original = {'a': 1, 'b': 20, 'c': 30, 'd': 4}

# build the list of new values as a list of tuples
update = [(k, form.get(k)) for k in form.keys() if form.get(k) != original.get(k, None)]

print update

# make the updates, making special calls as necessary
for k, v in update:
    if k == 'c':
        print "DO SOMETHING SPECIAL"
        original['c'] = v
    else:
        original[k] = v

print original
```

Produces

```
[('c', 3), ('b', 2)]
DO SOMETHING SPECIAL
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```